# Replace data between Square Brackets and ignore other occurences

Tags: text-processing

I have a csv file with below data

**Input**

```
"01","5","Male","[""No.**"",""**kg""]","","",""  
"02","6","FeMale","[""No.""]","","",""
```

I would like to replace the "," string which is between the square brackets but not the data outside the square brackets.

**Output:**

```
"01","5","Male","[""No.**,**kg""]","","",""  
"02","6","FeMale","[""No.""]","","",""
```

I tried below command, but it does replace data outside the square brackets, but not for all lines.

```
sed '/\[/,/\]/s/"",""/,/'
```

Comment: seems to me it's Python dictionary output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed '/\[/,/\]/s/"",""/,/'
```

This would look for a line with a `[`, then a line with a `]`, and between those lines, replace the first `"",""` encountered on each line. It doesn't really look at where the `[..]` are within a line.

---

As a zero-order try, something like this:

```
$ cat x
"01","5","Male","[""No.**"",""**kg""]","","","" 
$ sed 's/\(\[.*\)"",""\(.*\]\)/\1,\2/g' x
"01","5","Male","[""No.**,**kg""]","","",""
```

The pattern matches a `[`, anything, `"",""`, anything and a `]`, while capturing all but the `"",""`  so it can put the pieces back together.

This will break for stuff like `[..],"","",[..]` (where the brackets close before a `"",""` is seen, the pattern searches for a following `]`) and `[.."","".."",""..]` (with multiple `"",""` sequences inside the brackets, only one is removed).

Slightly more genarally with Perl, though this is a horrible substitution-within-substitution trick. You should probably use a proper parser instead:

```
$ cat y
no removal here: [...],"","",[...]
double removal here: [  "",""  "",""  ]
[""remove"",""here""],""not"",""here"",[""also"",""here""]

$ perl -pe 'sub x {$a = shift; $a =~ s/"",""/,/g; return $a;}
     s/(\[.*?\])/ x($1)  /eg  ' y
no removal here: [...],"","",[...]
double removal here: [  ,  ,  ]
[""remove,here""],""not"",""here"",[""also,here""]
```

(`.*?` is a non-greedy match, it stops as soon as it can, that is, at the first `]` in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/"Male/s/"",""/,/1' filename
```

Output:

```
"01","5","Male","[""No.**,**kg""]","","",""
"02","6","FeMale","[""No.""]","","",""
```